# NHibernate doesn't update many-to-many join table

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

I have three tables at my database: Images, ImageTags, Tags. Images and Tags have many-to-many relationship via ImagesTags table.
Images entity:

```
public class Image
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Tags entity:

```
public class Tag
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Images map:

```
public ImageMap()
{
    Table("Images");
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(m => m.Name).Length(100).Not.Nullable();

    HasManyToMany(f => f.Tags).Table("ImageTags")
       .LazyLoad().Inverse().Cascade.SaveUpdate(); 
}
```

Tags map:

```
public TagMap()
{
    Table("Tags");
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(m => m.Name).Length(100).Not.Nullable();
}
```

When I'm trying to update image, join table ImagesTag doesn't update, but other Image properties (Name) updates.

```
    public void Update (Image image)
    {
        session.SaveOrUpdate(image);
        session.Flush();
    }
```

Looking for some help, how to update join table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the mapping, explicitly in the **`.Inverse()`** setting

```
public ImageMap()
{
    ...
    HasManyToMany(f => f.Tags)
       .Table("ImageTags")
       .LazyLoad()
       .Inverse()         // WRONG, remove this
       .Cascade.SaveUpdate(); 
}
```

Why? This setting is there for cases, when we mapp both ends, e.g. if this would be on the Tag side:

```
public TagMap()
{
    ...
    HasManyToMany(f => f.Images)
       ....
}
```

In that case, we would have both ends, mapped, and we must instruct NHibernate, which end is the master. *In fact, by setting **`.Inverse()`** - we set the slave*

So, because in our case, we do not have the other end to be managing the pairing table... we cannot use inverse setting. That's it. Just remove it, NHibernate will behave as we'd expect

Comment: Great to see that sir ;) Enjoy amazing NHiberante ;)